# Construct a Fourier series that diverges almost everywhere.

Tags: analysis, fourier-series, constructive-mathematics, almost-everywhere

**Andrey N. Kolmogorov** was one of the greatest mathematicians and polymaths of the 20th century.

One of his first achievements was to [construct a Fourier series that diverges almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov).

How can one do such a construction?

How can one reason in order to come up with such a construction?

Thank you

Comment: [This](http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_II/contents/ICM_Vol_2_66.pdf) might be of interest to you.

Comment: yes to the point indeed, what about the second part of the question?

Comment: @DanZimm, want to post this as an answer (maybe also add a general reasoning behind the process)? Cheers